# Modifying the probability of sucess of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, randomness

This is motivated from a homework question. Let $A$ be an algorithm with probability of success equal to $q$ for solving a given problem. Let $p \in (0, 1)$. Find an algorithm that has a probability of success of at least $p$.

My idea so far is to run the algorithm multiple times and counting the number of times the algorithm succeeds and fails, but I don't know how I should combine the results to give an answer.

Comment: Can you test whether a solution is correct? If so, simply run $A$ a few times, and test each solution for correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can't.  Suppose the problem is a yes-or-no question, so that guessing randomly has a 50% chance of being right, but the problem is extremely hard or is unsolvable.  Thus there is a trivial algorithm $A$ (that guesses randomly) with $q=0.5$, but there might not be any way to solve it with success probability $p<0.5$.  For instance, maybe the problem is "guess what bit I am thinking of"; then there is no such solution.

However if you have a way to verify whether a solution is correct, then [as Yuval Filmus explains](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146364/modifying-the-probability-of-sucess-of-an-algorithm#comment308941_146364), you can do it.  You can simply run $A$ a few times, checking each time to see whether it gave the correct answer and outputting the first correct answer.  This will increase the probability of getting a correct answer.  You can figure out how many times you need to re-run $A$ using simple mathematics (hint: each run is independent).